# Python Groupby pandas sumas de strings y flotantes

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy tratando de unificar ciertas columnas de mi csv con pandas.
El problema es que quiero sumar los valores de Imp y Rev pero el de Categorias quiero que se junten y quedar algo asi:

```
sitio_id;url;Imp;Rev;Categorias
http://url.com/;19472;6,31;Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer
```

csv:

```
sitio_id;url;Imp; Rev ; eCPM ;Categorias
104521;http://url.com/;18984;15.8;0.83;Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer
70209;http://url.com/;488;0.51;1.04;Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer
```

Intente utilizar un group by:

```
df = df.groupby(['sitio_id', 'url'])['Imp','Rev'].sum()['Categorias'].apply(lambda x: "{%s}" % ', '.join(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por completar la respuesta de FJSevilla, quizás te interese que el resultado en "Categorias" no sea una mera concatenación de las cadenas del grupo, pues pueden aparecer categorías repetidas.

Al método `.agg()` puedes pasarle tus propias funciones. La función que escribas recibirá como parámetro una Serie cuyos elementos son las celdas del grupo, y tu función debe retornar un resultado que las agrupe de algún modo en un solo valor.

La función siguiente divide el contenido de cada celda (que es una cadena) por las comas, acumula las palabras en un conjunto (que se ocupa de que las repetidas aparezcan sólo una vez) y finalmente concatena los elementos del conjunto ordenándolos alfabéticamente y separándolos por comas:

```
def juntar(datos):
  categorias = set()
  for d in datos:
    categorias.update(d.split(","))
  return ", ".join(sorted(categorias))
```

Para usar esta función junto con `agg()`, es tan sencillo como:

```
df.groupby(['sitio_id', 'url']).agg(
     { "Imp": "sum",
       "Rev": "sum", 
       "Categorias": juntar})
```

A modo de ejemplo, partiendo de estos datos:

```
sitio_id;url;Imp;Rev;eCPM;Categorias
104521;http://url.com/;18984;15.8;0.83;Sports, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer
104521;http://url.com/;488;0.51;1.04;Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, World Soccer
```

El resultado sería:

```
                            Imp    Rev                                                                                          Categorias
sitio_id url                                                                                                                              
104521   http://url.com/  19472  16.31   Auto Racing,  Bodybuilding,  Boxing,  Pro Basketball,  Tennis,  Volleyball,  World Soccer, Sports
```

Donde puedes observar que las categorías salen ordenadas y sin repeticiones.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que intentas usar seleccionar la columna `Categorias` sobre la salida de `df.groupby(['sitio_id', 'url'])['Imp','Rev'].sum()`, que no va a tener dicha columna columna.

Para aplicar diferentes funciones a columnas cuando usas `groupby` puedes usar `agg` y pasar un diccionario con parejas `columna: función`. En tu caso sería algo así:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


csv = io.StringIO(
'''sitio_id;url;Imp;Rev;eCPM;Categorias
104521;http://url.com/;18984;15.8;0.83;Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer
104521;http://url.com/;488;0.51;1.04;Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer
''')


df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", skipinitialspace=True)
df2 = df.groupby(['sitio_id', 'url']).agg({'Imp': 'sum',
                                           'Rev': 'sum',
                                           "Categorias": lambda x: ', '.join(x)})
```

El contenido de `df2` es:

```
                            Imp    Rev                                                                                                                                                                                  Categorias
sitio_id url                             
104521   http://url.com/  19472  16.31   'Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer, Sports, Auto Racing, Bodybuilding, Boxing, Pro Basketball, Tennis, Volleyball, World Soccer'
```